# Nested Object w/ Checkboxes - mass-assignment even with accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, actionview

I thought that there should have been a simple solution to this, given that Rails 2.3 has this newfangled nested forms feature. Basically I want to create or update a user and assign them roles at the same time.

It seems like I'm doing everything right but I get the error **WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: roles_attrributes**.

I even tried changing the view to user[permissions_attrributes][role_id] because I thought that maybe the join table was confusing Rails.

Anyways, any suggestions on how this should actually work?

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :permissions
  has_many :roles, :through => :permissions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions
end
```

Excerpt from view (notice I tried and failed to get fields_for to generate what I want here, maybe that's my problem?)

```
<% for role in Role.all %>
 <%= check_box_tag( "user[roles_attrributes][id]",role.id) %>
 <%= role.rolename %>
 <br/>
<% end %>
```

Params coming across seem to be right:

```
    {"user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
"roles_attrributes"=>{"id"=>"2"}, ...
```

**Solution** A combination of me misspelling, not using attr_accessible, needing to access permissions_attributes, and the form being slightly off.

Model:

```
has_many :permissions, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :roles, :through => :permissions
accepts_nested_attributes_for :permissions
attr_accessible :permissions_attributes
```

View:

```
    <%  Role.all(:order => "rolename ASC").each_with_index do |role,idx| %>
    <%= check_box_tag( "user[permissions_attributes][#{idx}][role_id]",role.id) %>
    <%= role.rolename %>
    <br/>
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it sounds like this attribute isn't marked as safe for updating.  You should be able to fix it by adding the following to your model class:

```
attr_accessible :roles
```

or possibly:

```
attr_accessible :roles_attributes
```

If you look, you may already have an attr_accessible call you can add this to.  For more information this is documented here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002226

Comment: It was my understanding that accepts_nested_attributes_for did not require that. Anyways, I've tried both and neither worked.

Comment: That error message is definitely one that would be caused by an attr_protected or attr_accessible issue.  Also http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for indicates that is something to be aware of even with ANAF.  Possibly worth a closer look?

Answer (score 5):

If you correct the spelling of attributes in your `check_box_tag`, it looks like it should work.

```
<% for role in Role.all %>
 <%= check_box_tag( "user[roles_attributes][id]",role.id) %>
 <%= role.rolename %>
 <br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Good catch!  That would explain why the attribute was unrecognized =)